# Return ID of button when clicked Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

Simple problem I'm having:

**When I click a button in my Kivy/Python app, I want to gain access to the ID of that button.**

```
# Kivy code

Button:
    id: position_1
    on_press: app.access_button_id()
```

I have had various trial and error attempts but I cannot figure it out. The button is nested as follows (as part of a bigger app), if this is a factor in my problem:

```
FloatLayout:
    AnchorLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    FloatLayout:
                        Button:
                            id: position_1
                            on_press: app.access_button_id()
```

Here is my Python code, which returns all of the id's. That's as close as I have got:

```
# Python code

def access_button_id(name):
    print(self.root.ids)
```

The problem I've got is that I don't even know *what* I should be looking at in the documentation as I do not fully understand the terminology yet, so I can't find the right information to learn from.

EDIT:

The (name) passed into the function is for some other functionality, not related to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the id - you set it yourself. These are mostly used as a hard-coded values in your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        id: id_value_1
        text: 'Print my id'
        on_press: print({'id_value_1': self.proxy_ref})
    Button:
        id: id_value_2
        text: 'Print all ids'
        on_press: print(root.ids)
''')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        widget = MyWidget()
        print({'id_value_1': widget.ids['id_value_1']})
        return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Why do you need id of a Button if you already have an access to it? What are you trying to accomplish?

---

EDIT

An example solution to problem mentioned in the comment:

```
import random
import functools

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'B1'
        on_press: root.open_popup(self)
    Button:
        text: 'B2'
        on_press: root.open_popup(self)
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def open_popup(self, caller):
        fun = functools.partial(self.rename, caller)
        popup = Popup(
            title='Test popup',
            content=Button(
                text='rename',
                on_press=fun
            ),
            size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400)
        )
        popup.open()

    def rename(self, caller, *args):
        caller.text = ''.join(chr(random.randint(48, 90)) for i in range(5))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Ah I see. I have a large number of these buttons - at the moment when pressed they call a popup which has a list of options in it, and selecting an option replaces the button text. The options are the same for each button, so I just wanted to write one function that applies the new text to the button that was clicked. Currently I have a unique function for each button because I'm using hardcoded id's.

Comment: You can pass the reference to widget itself to your popup. I added an example implementation.

Comment: I have got this so that the popup contains my list of options and clicking any one allocates a random string to the button that was initially clicked, so thank you that has got me a step closer. Now I just need to work out how to replace that random string with the text from the option that was chosen.