# get the id of button from kv language file

Tags: python, kivy

I have all the layout set up in a kv language file. Then when the button is pressed, it call a popup that a file chooser. Because I have two button that uses the filechooser function, I want to set up a if statement to do different thing depend on the id of the button pressed.

something like this

```
#the onpress function
def show_load(self):
    content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
    self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                        size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
    self._popup.open()
#store the path
def load(self,path,filename):
    global newfilepath
    global oldfilepath
    if buttonid==newfile
       newfilepath=os.path.join(path, filename[0])
    else 
       oldfilepath=os.path.join(path, filename[0])
    self.dismiss_popup()
```

I'm struggling with how do I get the button id at load function. I tried self.ids but this generated all the widget on the screen instead of the one pressed.

.KV file

```
<checker_ui>:
    rows:2
    cols:1
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
            id:this_week_btn
            text: 'This Week Report'
            size_hint:(1, None)
            height: root.height/12
            on_release: root.show_load(self)
        Button:
            id:last_week_btn
            text: 'Last Week Report'
            size_hint:(1, None)
            height: root.height/12
            on_release: root.show_load(self)
        Button:
            id:confirm_btn
            text: 'Start Checking'
            size_hint:(1, None)
            height: root.height/12

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id:entry
            text:'Select This Week\'s report'
            font_size:18
            multiline:True
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, .5, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Comment: Have you checked this out?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841321/return-id-of-button-when-clicked-kivy-python

Comment: show your .kv.....

Comment: The solution in the thread doesn't seem to fit my issue because I'm trying to call the id in the load function and not show_load function. Edited with my .kv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

If you print the *button's id* at method *show_load*, it will display *None*, therefore you will have to save the button's text and use it in the *load* method.

[Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> The Kv Language provides a way to do this using id’s. Think of them as
>   class level variables that can only be used in the Kv language.

In Python code, to reference the *id*, one can use *self.ids.id-name.text* or *self.ids['id-name'].text* or *self.obj-name.text* whereby *obj-name* is an *ObjectProperty* and hooked up to the *id-name* defined in the Kv file.

> When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with
>   id’s and places them in this self.ids dictionary type property.

## Example

### Snippets - main.py

```
class checker_ui(GridLayout):
    btn_text = StringProperty('')

    # the on_release function
    def show_load(self, instance):
        # save the button's text because button's id is None
        self.btn_text = instance.text
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    # store the path
    def load(self, path, filename):
        global newfilepath
        global oldfilepath
        if self.btn_text == newfile:
           newfilepath = os.path.join(path, filename[0])
        else:
           oldfilepath = os.path.join(path, filename[0])
        self.dismiss_popup()
```